# Error when connecting SQL server to Power Automate

Tags: sql-server, power-automate

When connecting using my local gateway, I get this error:

> Failed to create connection for connection id
> '/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sql/connections/shared-sql-513a7282-460c-4ad2-bd55-954e83289509'.
> Multiple errors occurred: ''. Please see details.

I am not able to see the details it is referencing. Is there something I am missing?[image]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots or more details of the problem, for example, which page the error is occurring on.

Comment: The error occurs when I am inputting the details for the SQL server on Power Automate. I downloaded the on-premises gateway and am trying to use both windows authentication and SQL authentication in the Power Automate page but when pressing `create` it gives me this error.

Comment: What's the status of the gateway on the "Date > Gateways" page?

Comment: In the gateways tab it says `Online | You are running the latest gateway version.`

Comment: This is strange. I haven't been able to replicate the error by entering an invalid server name, db name, user name or password. I also changed a the SQL Server settings to not allow remote connections, but this also didn't produce the error. If you create a new DB and user and set the server name to "localhost" do you get the same error?

Comment: I tried that and I get the same error, not sure what to do. Is there a guide, documentation/video I can look into? It keeps showing that same error:
`Failed to create connection for connection id '/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sql/connections/shared-sql-21350618-db86-48a6-840b-092054eeebbe'. Multiple errors occurred: ''. Please see details.`

Comment: You could try checking that your power automate environment region and the gateway region are the same. See the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/check-if-gateway-is-the-right-region

Comment: I checked and that is correct. Could it have something to do with my license? I purchased the $15 one so I can get premium connections.

Comment: It could possibly be an issue. Are you using a personal account? The gateway install instructions say that "you need to sign in with either a work account or a school account", so that could be an issue. Also, try running a "Network ports test", see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-communication#network-ports-test

Comment: The email I am using is `xxxx@MunSa975.onmicrosoft.com` and I saw someone else use an account like this and got it working. Not sure if the account specifically is the issue. Also, I ran the port test and it said 'Success" for each.

Comment: I have a similar account so that should be ok. There might be more info in the gateway logs. To access these, click on the "Export logs" link on the gateway "Diagnostics" screen. This will create a zip file. Within that zip file will be a file named "GatewayErrorsTIMESTAMP.log". This may contain more info on the issue.

Comment: This is what that file says:

`Starting trace on 9/21/2022 11:17:18 PM UTC
UserDomainName: NT SERVICE
UserName: PBIEgwService
MachineName: DESKTOP-GE2L2VQ
Log File Count: 20
Log File Set Total Size: 52428800`



`Starting trace on 9/21/2022 11:17:23 PM UTC
UserDomainName: NT SERVICE
UserName: PBIEgwService
MachineName: DESKTOP-GE2L2VQ
Log File Count: 20
Log File Set Total Size: 52428800`

Comment: Since there are no errors being picked up by the gateway I don't think the connection is reaching your SQL server. I'll carry on investigating tomorrow.

Comment: Alright, I will stay up and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some digging but I found the solution.
After you download the data gateway software from Microsoft and set it up with an `onmicrosoft.com` domain, the missing step is to go in the `PowerBI` website.
There you check in `Settings, Manage Gateways, On-premises data gateways`. If your gateway is shown, then the final step is to create a data cluster in `Data sources`. For some reason, my SQL server login I created in my security did not work, so I decided to use the Windows authentication, as it was easier. Note, if your PC is logged in with a Microsoft account, your login is your computer's domain and password. If it is local, then you put your computer's name (e.x. mine is tams).

After creating the data cluster for the gateway, go back to Power Automate and connect to your local SQL server again. This time, the gateway will appear as an option in the dropdown menu, instead of typing it in. Input your information exactly the same way you did in `PowerBI` and it should work.

Comment: do you know how to connect SQL server that accessed from Virtual Machine ?  usually i query many data by accessing the SQL Server on VM, but i want to try to automate certain script using power automate, in VM the SQL Server using SQL Server Authentication, but i dont know how to get the gateway to connect it to power automate, thank you in advance